# owl carousel not working after ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, owl-carousel

i use jquery 1.11 and this code to ajax load wordpress post content in sidebar . everything is good but jquery functions of owl carousel not work and the carousel in post content not showing anything.
ajaxify code to load post content:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
$(".post-link").click(function(){
    var post_link = $(this).attr("href")+' #content';
    $("#single-post-container").html("loading ...");
    $("#single-post-container").load(post_link);
return false;
});

});
```

is there any way to solve this problem and conflict?
best regards.

Comment: have you tried creating the two functions i posted on my question which seemed to help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802064/how-to-reinitialize-owl-carousel-after-ajax-call/27904194#27904194

Comment: yes i tried it. but not working. hope you could help me .

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
jQuery(function () {
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
      jQuery(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
    }, 1500);
  });
});
```