# owl carousel, ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax, owl-carousel

I'm creating a page that loads external content via ajax.

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $("#ajax-container")load("external-file.php");
});
```

This works but the content in the external files contain a Owl Carousel, which appear in the loaded html, but do not (re)initialise.

According to the Owl docs, and the simialr post here ([How to reinitialize Owl Carousel after ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802064)) I need to destroy and then reinitiate the carousel.
This works perfectly when attached to an independant click.

```
$(".button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $("#carousel").data('owlCarousel').destroy();
    $("#carousel").owlCarousel();
});
```

but I need this to happen without an additional click once the ajax file has loaded. I have tried all of the following methods with no luck.

```
// adding to original
$(".link").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $("#ajax-container")load("external-file.php");
    $("#carousel").data('owlCarousel').destroy();
    $("#carousel").owlCarousel();
});

// in addition to original
$(".link-second-classname").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $("#carousel").data('owlCarousel').destroy();
    $("#carousel").owlCarousel();
});

// ajaxComplete
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $("#carousel").data('owlCarousel').destroy();
    $("#carousel").owlCarousel();
});

// ajaxSuccess
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $("#carousel").data('owlCarousel').destroy();
    $("#carousel").owlCarousel();
});
```

Any help or suggestions would be massively appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to initialize the carousel using the callback parameter of the jquery load method.

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#ajax-container").load("external-file.php", function() {
        $("#carousel").owlCarousel();
    });
});
```